# Equivalence of formulations for the Gauss-Seidel iterative method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Having gone to Wolfram's page about the [Gauss-Seidel Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gauss-SeidelMethod.html) to solve systems of the type

$$Ax = b$$

I found two formulations for the calculation of the several iterates.

For the first one, you compute the $k$-iterate component by component with

$$x_i^{(k)} = \frac{b_i - \sum_{j<i}a_{ij}x_j^{(k)} - \sum_{j>i}a_{ij}x_j^{(k-1)}}{a_{ii}} \tag{1}$$

while on the second formulation, you write

$$x^{(k)} = (D-L)^{-1}(Ux^{(k-1)} + b) \tag{2}$$

where $D, -L, -U$ are, respectively, the diagonal, strictly lower triangular and strictly upper triangular parts of $A$.

I want to show these two formulations compute the same thing. For that, I tried taking the $i$-th component of $(2)$ to show it was the same as $(1)$. For that I did: (assuming $L, U$ are the strictly lower/upper triangular parts of $A$, respectively)

$$\begin{cases}(D+L)_{ij}^{-1} = l_{ij}\\(Ux^{(k-1)})_j = \sum_{t=1}^{n}u_{jk}x_t^{(k-1)}\end{cases}$$

and then

$$\begin{align}x_i^k &= (D+L)_i^{-1}(b - Ux^{(k-1)})\\
&= (D+L)^{-1}_i b - (D+L)_i^{-1}Ux^{(k-1)}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} l_{ij}b_j - \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}(Ux^{(k-1)})_j\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} l_{ij}b_j - \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}(\sum_{t=1}^n u_{jt}x_t^{(k-1)})
\end{align}$$

which is a dead end to me, as I have no clue of what to do now. Can someone help me out? Is this the correct approach? Or is there a better path?

Answer (score 1):

Better use
$$
(D-L)x^{(k)}=Ux^{(k-1)}+b
$$
as point of departure to avoid dealing with the coordinates of the inverse matrix. Writing this in coordinates should directly translate into the first formula.